# Vim <A-j> Keybinding for 10j moves cursor to the right

Tags: vim

I've recently mapped `10j` to `<A-j>` and `10k` to `<A-k>`, which is seemingly quite amazing, but there is one problem with it:

When I normally type `10j` (not using the shortcut), it will just move 10 rows down vertically but not move horizontally at all (given the lines have the same length), but when I use `<A-j>` it will always (well, interestingly enough, not always, but most of the times) also move one letter to the right.

Funnily enough, this happens only for `<A-j>`, whereas `<A-k>` works as intended. How can I prevent that? And maybe most importantly: Why is that?

If it helps, these are my other keybindings:

```
nnoremap K K<C-w>L
nnoremap <A-h> :set hls!<cr>
nnoremap / :set hlsearch<cr>/
nnoremap <A-j> 10j 
nnoremap <A-k> 10k
nnoremap <A-w> W
nnoremap <A-b> B
nnoremap <A-v> V
nnoremap <A-m> '
nnoremap <A-p> "+p
nnoremap <A-y> "+y
nnoremap <A-4> $
nnoremap <A-3> 0
nnoremap Y y$

vnoremap <A-h> :set hls!<cr>
vnoremap / :set hlsearch<cr>/
vnoremap <A-j> 10j
vnoremap <A-k> 10k
vnoremap <A-w> W
vnoremap <A-b> B
vnoremap <A-v> V
vnoremap <A-m> '
vnoremap <A-p> "+p
vnoremap <A-y> "+y
vnoremap <A-4> $
vnoremap <A-3> 0
```

Yeah, I like the alt-key a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason to use alt instead if shift for eg w? They seem the same to me...

Comment: The alt-key is always more or less under my left thumb, so it's generally faster and more comfortable for me to use than the shift-key, which requires some pinky-finger-acrobatics. Also, I never use the right shift-key, maybe that would help.
I guess the way I type may be quite idiosyncratic, but it's fast, so I never bothered to unlearn it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a trailing *space* character at the end of your mapping:

```
:nnoremap <A-j>
n  <M-j>       * 10j<Space>
```

`<Space>` is the same command as [`l`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#l); it moves a character to the right (where possible).

The right-hand side in a mapping is taken literally (up to the end of the line or a `|` command separator). Another common mistake is appending a `" comment` to a mapping definition.

#### Plugin recommendations

If you regularly stumble over trailing whitespace (it's generally frowned upon in many coding styles, and tools like Git also highlight it as problematic), my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) can alert you to those, and the [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) can remove them for you. (The plugin pages have links to alternative plugins.)

Comment: Plugins not needed: listchars shows trailing whitespace when configured (and git hooks can reject commits with it). Deleting it is (more or less) a one-line command definition.